# Linear Layout in side Relative Layout I want to change the color of Relative Layout on Press.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have the following code:

Selector code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        </shape></item>


</selector>
```

Layout Code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_row_background_selector"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_list_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameCreationDateView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change the color of Relative Layout when I click on it. However the above code didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Note: I use the layout as part of the code in my listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your layout as part of listview, then why you are giving selector to that layout. You can make use of selector in listview.

**Pls try this out. It may sometimes help you:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
     >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_row_background_selector"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_list_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameCreationDateView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't I have my own custom listeners for the list view so the list view select wouldn't work.

Comment: Really what you like to do. Will you please explain me briefly?

Comment: Ok, I add my own custom listener to the listview row which is a Relative View to achieve functions like swipe left and swipe right. I noticed after I add the listeners on click on the listview does not change the listview item background any more. So I guess I have to add it to the RelativeLayout which is the element that contains in the list view.

Comment: ok. sometimes the layout may confuse us by the way of their working. anyway i edited your code lightly. so please check it out and reply me.

Comment: Just added another Relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help..

list_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

list_selector_pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#5D9438"/>
        <size android:width="1dip"/>
        <size android:height="1dip"/>

    </shape>
```

add `android:background="@drawable/list_selector"` to ur relative layout..

Comment: I tested my own selector, the selector works on LinearLayout the child of RelativeLayout if I put android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_row_background_selector" on the linear layout. So, I don't think it has anything to do with the selector code.

Comment: I guess the problem is detecting when I press the relative layout, since linear layout is on top of relative layout.

Comment: since u've kept match parent for linear layout, its consuming whole of relative layout.. may be no touch for rel layout is possible.. it'll work for linear layout only

Comment: Is it possible to detect the touch on the listview in this case? I noticed if I put Relative Layout on the listview the touch got disabled.

Comment: rel layout is disabled because u kept linear layout completely on top of it.. touch on listview is detected on onItemClick() only.. but that's not useful here..